# Add extra information to the Symfony2 profiler timeline

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

My application uses AWS DynamoDB and I want to be able to track the time the Dynamo request takes, just like it would if I was using Doctrine or Propel.

Some controllers also access a bunch of custom services, ideally I'd be able to track the time each of them take as well.

Is there a way to add some hooks into my code before and after these blocks of code to track the time and add it into the profiler timeline?

Comment: I do wonder the same. I have a controller that takes 10 seconds to execute and I see a straight 10-seconds-long line and wished to place 5 to 10 hooks to see "what is what is taking so much time".

Answer (score 3):

i think you could use this new component "Stop watch"

http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-2-new-stopwatch-component